# Update an XML node that is stored as string in Database

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

Can i get to know the SQL query to replace an XML node's value(Which differs for each row) to a new value(Common to all rows)?

In case the XML is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<EmployeeDetail xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Name>MyName</Name>
  <Age>20</Age>
  <Salary>15000</Salary>
</EmployeeDetail>
```

I need to update all the XML column's `<Salary>DifferingSalary</Salary>` to `<Salary>10000</Salary>`

Tried:

```
DECLARE @salary VARCHAR(10) = '10000';

UPDATE TABLE_NAME
SET [COLUMN_NAME].modify('replace value of 
    (/EmployeeDetail/Salary/text())[1] 
    with (sql:variable("@salary"))
');
```

Output:

> Cannot call methods on nvarchar(max).

Note: The XML is stored as a string in database.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example. Please refer to the following link:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
Please provide the following:  
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it. 
(3) Desired output based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;)

Comment: I've added. Please check the updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following methods.

It shows how to modify the `<salary>` element value when:

- xmldata column is XML data type.
- xmldata column is NVARCHAR(MAX) data type.

> SQL #1

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, xmldata XML);
INSERT INTO @tbl ( xmldata) VALUES
(N'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<EmployeeDetail xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <Name>MyName</Name>
    <Age>20</Age>
    <Salary>15000</Salary>
</EmployeeDetail>');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

-- before
SELECT * FROM @tbl;

DECLARE @salary VARCHAR(10) = '10000';

UPDATE @tbl
SET xmldata.modify('replace value of 
    (/EmployeeDetail/Salary/text())[1] 
    with (sql:variable("@salary"))
');

-- after
SELECT * FROM @tbl;
```

> SQL #2

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, xmldata NVARCHAR(MAX));
INSERT INTO @tbl ( xmldata) VALUES
(N'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<EmployeeDetail xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <Name>MyName</Name>
    <Age>20</Age>
    <Salary>15000</Salary>
</EmployeeDetail>');

DECLARE @realXML TABLE (ID INT, realXML XML);
-- DDL and sample data population, end

-- populate temporary table
INSERT INTO @realXML
SELECT ID, cast(xmldata AS XML)
FROM @tbl;

DECLARE @salary VARCHAR(10) = '10000';

/*
Unfortunately, we can not assign from a xml.modify() statement. 
Modify works on a variable and a column only. 
Also, we cannot use modify on a CAST().
*/
-- update temporary table
UPDATE @realXML
SET realXML.modify('replace value of 
            (/EmployeeDetail/Salary/text())[1] 
            with (sql:variable("@salary"))
        ');

-- update real table 
UPDATE tbl
SET xmldata = CAST(t.realXML AS NVARCHAR(MAX))
FROM @realXML AS t INNER JOIN @tbl AS tbl
ON tbl.ID = t.ID;
```

Comment: Cannot call methods on nvarchar(max). is the error i get.

Comment: I updated the answer. It is always better to use a proper data type, the XML data type in this case.